# Install ruby 1.9.2-head via RVM fails during compilation ('__rvm_make -j2')

Tags: ruby, crouton-os

**Background:** 
Running ubuntu 14.04 (xfce) via crouton on a Hp Chromebook 14.

**Overview:**
I'm attempting to install ruby 1.9.2 via rvm.

RVM says 1.9.2 requires 2.x and installs without problem.
Upon following thru with 1.9.2 it fails during compilation and aborts installation.
*I've ran the install command x3, same error

**Error:**

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j2',
showing last 15 lines of /home/alkarion/.rvm/log/1401550868_ruby-1.9.2-head/make.log
In file included from parse.y:22:0:
parse.h:188:21: warning: ‘struct parser_params’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
 int yyparse (struct parser_params *parser);
                     ^
parse.h:188:21: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [enabled by default]
parse.c: In function ‘ruby_yyparse’:
parse.c:4501:7: error: too few arguments to function ‘yylex’
     {
       ^
parse.y:325:12: note: declared here
 static int yylex(void*, void*);
            ^
make: *** [parse.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

**Here is the code prior to error:**

```
$ rvm install ruby-1.9.2
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/alkarion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
HEAD is now at d1b23d1 merge revision(s) 36533:
remote: Counting objects: 19, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 11 (delta 8), reused 11 (delta 8)
Unpacking objects: 100% (11/11), done.
From git://github.com/ruby/ruby
   06fb823..9529ed2  trunk      -> origin/trunk
From git://github.com/ruby/ruby
 * branch            ruby_1_9_2 -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
Copying from repo to src path...
ruby-1.9.2-head - #applying patch /home/alkarion/.rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch.
ruby-1.9.2-head - #autoreconf.
ruby-1.9.2-head - #configuring..........................................
ruby-1.9.2-head - #post-configuration.
ruby-1.9.2-head - #compiling.............
```

Comment: Why do you want 1.9.2-head? The head versions are not always in the best shape.

Comment: @tadman 1.9.2-head seems to have been chosen by RVM. The command was just 'install 1.9.2' it goes ahead and adds the '-head' variation.
I need 1.9.2 to follow some educational documentation, which explicitly requires ruby 1.9.2. I'll see if I can try to get a 'headless' 1.9.2.

Comment: Yes, I get exactly the same error. As @Josh says, p320 doesn't have the problem.

Answer (score 2):

ruby-1.9.2-p320 appears to bypass this issue.

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p320
```

I'm not sure what the problem is yet but was able to successfully install ruby 1.9.2 and ruby 2.0 via rvm a week or two ago on ubuntu 14.04 but today I received the same error that you did.  Also, I noticed that ruby 2.1 was installed as a dependency rather than 2.0 so that could be part of the problem.

- josh